# Use only one feature flag attribute with multiple use statements in Rust

Tags: rust, rust-cargo, conditional-compilation

Is it possible to use only one feature flag attribute for multiple use statements in Rust?
Something like this:

```
#[cfg(feature = "my-flag")]
{
  use crypto::sha2::Sha256;
  use ethers::utils::keccak256;
}
```

**Note:** The compiler throws a Syntax Error for the above.

Currently I have to use one flag attribute for each use statement like this:

```
#[cfg(feature = "my-flag")]
use crypto::sha2::Sha256;
#[cfg(feature = "my-flag")]
use ethers::utils::keccak256;
```

Can this be shortened?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`cfg-if`](https://docs.rs/cfg-if):

```rust
cfg_if::cfg_if! {
    if #[cfg(feature = "my-flag")] {
        use crypto::sha2::Sha256;
        use ethers::utils::keccak256;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can combine them into one `use` statement:

```
#[cfg(feature = "my-flag")]
use {crypto::sha2::Sha256, ethers::utils::keccak256};
```